# How to test a Cloud Function in Google Cloud Platform (GCP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to find the answer to this but am unable to find it anywhere. On the Cloud Functions section in the Google Cloud Platform console there is a section title 'Testing' but I have no idea what one is supposed to put here to test the function, i.e. syntax.

I have attached an image for clarity:
[image: I have attached an image for clarity]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

HTTPS Callable functions must be called using the POST method, the Content-Type must be application/json or application/json; charset=utf-8, and the body must contain a field called data for the data to be passed to the method.

Example body:

```
{
    "data": {
        "aString": "some random string",
        "anInt": 57,
        "aFloat": 1.23
    }
}
```

If you are calling a function by creating your own http request, you may find it more flexible to use a regular HTTPS function instead.

[Click Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) for more information

Answer (score 2):

Example with the Cloud Function default Hello_World that is inserted automatically whenever you create a new Cloud Function:

```py
def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        return f'Hello World!'
```

[image]

Must be tested with a json as the input args:

```json
{
    "message": "Hello Sun!"
}
```

Out in the Testing Tab:

```
Hello Sun!
```

[image]

In the Testing tab editor: since we give the function the args in form of a json as we would elsewise write them like in `python3 -m main.py MY_ARG`, and since "message" is a key of that json, it is found by the `elif` and returns the value of the dictionary key as the message, instead of "Hello World". If we run the script without json args, `else:` is reached in the code, and output is "Hello World!":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple Tests for Cloud Pub/Sub:

```
{"data":"This is data"}
```

Base64 'Hello World !' message :

```
{"data":"SGVsbG8gV29ybGQgIQ=="}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be the same as `gcloud functions call`, with the JSON required being the same as the `--data` provided in the CLI.

You can check [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/direct) for examples using the CLI, and [the CLI documentation itself](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/call) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could test you cloud function.

1) Use a google emulator locally if you want to test your code before deployment.
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator. 
This would give you a similar localhost HTTP endpoint that you can send request to for testing your function.

2) Using GUI on deployed function: The triggering event is the json object that the function expects in the request body. For example:

```
    {
      "key": "value"
    }
```

Based on your function code dependency for the request it should trigger the function.