# Unable to install pandas for python

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I am trying to install pandas for python but I keep getting very long error messages. So I tried the following:

- Uninstall and resinstall python version 3.10.0
- Install pandas through command prompt by navigating to directory
  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
  and running pip install pandas
- I also tried using pip3 install pandas
- I tried to install a previous version of pandas but still getting the same error

Here is the error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1288]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\motaz>cd .C:\Users\motaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\motaz>cd C:\Users\motaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts

C:\Users\motaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts>pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.3.3.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\motaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\motaz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-_jyoyc51\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\motaz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qf94j_f0\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=51.0.0' wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and (platform_machine!='"'"'arm64'"'"' or platform_system!='"'"'Darwin'"'"') and platform_machine!='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.18.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and (platform_machine!='"'"'arm64'"'"' or platform_system!='"'"'Darwin'"'"') and platform_machine!='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"' and (platform_machine!='"'"'arm64'"'"' or platform_system!='"'"'Darwin'"'"') and platform_machine!='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.2; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.2; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy>=1.20.0; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'arm64'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'Darwin'"'"'' 'numpy>=1.20.0; python_version=='"'"'3.9'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'arm64'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'Darwin'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (234 lines):
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, Python 3.10 was enabled for `pandas` [a few days ago](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/e7efd02c71c48c7968b2f8fdb845a0b0bf61a3fa). However, the last release (1.3.3) was published on September, 12.

You have to wait for a new release of Pandas to install it using Python 3.10. Until that happens, you can stay with a lower version of Python (like some users suggested).

Comment: Just as a note: Pandas has released a new version a week ago. It is now installable with Python 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that you had, I had installed an older version of python (namely python 3.7.7). The issue was resolved. As far as I have heard, pandas and numpy packages weren't "ready" for the 3.10 python.
So check for older versions.

Answer (score 0):

You must download the version 3.9.7 and that´s ok when to install pandas.
I had that uninstall the version 3.10 (I used the program revo uninstaller)

Answer (score 0):

I had to [`3.9.7`](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-397/) and then install pandas.
I had to uninstall the version [`3.10`](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3100/) (I used the program revo uninstaller) to do this.

---

Then, 15 days ago ([13rd October 2021](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/e7efd02c71c48c7968b2f8fdb845a0b0bf61a3fa)) they enabled the install of pandas for Python 3.10.
Now you can simply install it from the `cmd.exe`/`prompt`.