# Heatmap error :'NoneType' object is not callable when using with dataframe

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I have this issue with heatmap from seaborn. I don't know how, but seaborn.heatmap() refuses to take in dataframe, it instead show the mentioned error. Seaborn, matplotlib and pandas is up-to-date and I'm using python 3.10 on Visual Studio. The code is just a sample code from seaborn.heatmap itself:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
ax=sns.heatmap(flights)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please add a trace of errors. Thanks

Comment: @Dilettant is this what you want? I'm sorry if I'm mistaken: Stack trace:
 >  File "D:\baitaplaptrinh\lamchoi\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 6, in <module> (Current frame)
 >    ax=sns.heatmap(flights)

Comment: I've been running into the same issue. It looks like something is setting `np.core.numeric.dtype` to None. When a dtype check occurs (part of Matplotlib's plotting), the `np.core.numeric.dtype()` function is called. Since this has been set to None by *something*, it raises the error you've noted above. Still trying to figure out how this is happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Python 3.9 (or 3.8, 3.7, 3.6) as it seems like both [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69586701/unable-to-install-pandas-for-python) and [plt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281638/why-can-i-not-run-matplotlib-on-python-3-10) are not quite ready to be used with Python 3.10:

[image]

Comment: I dont know if this is the right one, but in the output, it said:Stack trace:
 >  File "D:\baitaplaptrinh\lamchoi\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 6, in <module> (Current frame)
 >    ax=sns.heatmap(flights)

Comment: I'd love to, but my reputation is too low, sorry